# Create Pane level controllers

Tags: javafx

I have an accordion control with 14 panes. Is there a way to attache a separate controller to each pane? The FXML allows me to specify a controller, but the loader rejects it.

Comment: Define each pane in a separate FXML file (or maybe just one FXML file if they are essentially the same), use [`<fx:include>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements) to include the pane FXMLs in the "main" FXML.

Comment: I used that method with tab views. I will try it with the panes.